# How to add a file on a remote server using Python

Tags: python, ssh, server

I want to save a file from my laptop to a remote server using python but i get the error : 
OSError: Failure 
from the second last command.

```
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='ipaddress',username='user',password='passwd', port='port')

ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put('laptop/path/to/file/','server/saving/path/')
ftp_client.close()
```

Additionally, because a file with a same name already exists on that file i want to replace it with this one. Any ideas why this code is not working?

I do not want to use ssh on my terminal because i want the python script to automatically do this every week while the file is updated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: OSError: Failure
This was only the error message. But i solved the problem. Thanks a lot! @AMC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scp package to do secure copy up to and from the remote server.  Something like this.

```
from scp import SCPClient

....

scp = SCPClient(ssh_client.get_transport())
payload = os.path.join(...path to file)
scp.put(payload, '/path/on/server/')
```

Comment: if i change the last command to scp.put(payload, 'saving/directory/on/server/') the file will be saved on the wanted directory on the server replacing the already existing file with the same name?

Comment: @EAS the payload is the path to a directory or file that you want to send up to the server, you can specify the remote path for your upload to go in, or in the case of uploading a file, you can specify a remote path and file name.  Such as scp.put('test.txt', '~/test2.txt') for instance.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you solved my problem. Thanks a lot!!